# Mass action law in semiconductors

Tags: semiconductors

In thermal equilibrium, the mass action law states that $$n_{h}n_{e}=n_{i}^{2},$$
where \$n_{h}\$ is the equilibrium concentration of holes and which equals to the equilibrium concentration of conduction electrons \$n_{e}\$
$$n_{h}=n_{e}=n_{i}.$$

After doping, for example with electrons donor, arsenic for example, we would have $$ N_{D}>>n_{e}$$

After doping, do we still have a thermodynamic equilibrium?

Comment: Thermodynamic equilibrium has nothing to do with doping. If the temperature of the silicon is the same as that of the environment, then it is in thermodynamic equilibrium.

Comment: @sarthak, that's not a great definition.  When all the derivatives are equal to zero, then you're at equilibrium.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wikipedia page on this topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_action_law_(electronics)) where the mass action law is written as follows:
(where n is free electron concentration, and p the free hole concentration.)
$$  n_{}p_{}=n_{i}^{2}  $$

In place of the above original $$ n_{h}n_{e}=n_{i}^{2} $$

The explanation continues with the extended equation of
$$ n_{}p_{}=N_{c}N_{v}exp(-E_{g}/k_{B}T_{})=n_{i}^{2} $$

and ends with the statement:

"The above equation holds true even for lightly doped extrinsic semiconductors as the product *np* is independent of doping concentration."

So from that I'd venture to say that after doping, you would still have a thermodynamic equilibrium.

.